# How to find the third derivative of the function given by $\rho=\tan(\rho+\phi)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> Given that $\rho=\tan(\rho+\phi)$, how to find $\frac{d^3 \rho}{d\phi^3}$?

Answer is:  $$-\frac{2(5+8\rho^2+3\rho^4)}{\rho^8}$$

I start  from  $$\rho=\tan(\rho+\phi) \tag{1}  $$ 
and use
$$\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan a +\tan b}{1-\tan a \tan b}$$ 
On applying this to eq (1)  :

$$\tan \phi +\tan \rho=\rho(1-\tan\phi \tan\rho)$$ On further substitution i got:

$$\tan\phi+\tan \rho=\rho-\rho \tan\phi \tan\rho$$please can someone help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

I think that the easier way is implicit differentiation. Start with $$F=\rho-\tan(\rho+\phi)=0$$ from which $$F'_{\rho}=1-\sec ^2(\rho +\phi )$$ $$F'_{\phi}=-\sec ^2(\rho +\phi )$$ So, now $$\frac{d\rho}{d\phi}=\frac{\sec ^2(\rho +\phi )}{1-\sec ^2(\rho +\phi )}=-1-\cot^2(\rho+\phi)=-1-\frac{1}{\rho^2}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

**Added later**

In the first step, what was found is that $$\rho '(\phi )=-1-\frac{1}{\rho(\phi)^2}$$ Continuing the differentiation with respect to $\phi$ $$\rho ''(\phi )=\frac{2 \rho '(\phi )}{\rho (\phi )^3}$$ $$\rho ^{(3)}(\phi )=\frac{2 \rho ''(\phi )}{\rho (\phi )^3}-\frac{6 \rho '(\phi )^2}{\rho (\phi )^4}$$ $$\rho^{(4)}(\phi )=\frac{2 \rho ^{(3)}(\phi )}{\rho (\phi )^3}+\frac{24 \rho '(\phi )^3}{\rho (\phi
   )^5}-\frac{18 \rho '(\phi ) \rho ''(\phi )}{\rho (\phi )^4}$$ and so on

Comment: @ claud Leibivici...im terribly  sorry sir,n thank you once again :)

Comment: Again, you are and always will be very welcome. Cheers :-)

Comment: Sir, how did you get$ (-1-tan^2(\rho+\phi))$

Comment: @ claude leibivici sir, on simplifying $$\frac{sec ^2(\rho +\phi )}{1- sec ^2(\rho +\phi )}$$ in this manner  $$\frac{1+tan ^2(\rho +\phi )}{-tan^2(\rho +\phi )}$$  i got :-$$-cot^2(\rho +\phi)-1$$then how did you get $$-1-\tan^2(\rho+\phi)$$ and sorry for the trouble i'm causing,please sir, can you tell my mistake??

Comment: @Nikhil01. You are perfectly right ! I made a mistake. No trouble and congratulations for showing me how bad I can be. Cheers :-)

Comment: Sorry if I was rude, sir and thank you

Comment: You were not rude at all, be sure ! And I am happy you found a mistake and not trusted me since my answer was totally wrong as you pointed out. You are and always will be very welcome. Cheers :-)

Comment: Sir,can I chat with you in chat room please,i have a few doubts i intend to clarify

Comment: OK. You launch the system and I join you !

Comment: Give me a second, sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16980/discussion-between-nikhil01-and-claude-leibovici).

Comment: I don't know what is going on ! I am unable to talk in the chat room. I see you there !

Comment: i sent you a request...just click on previous comment

Comment: i.e"lets continue our discussion in chat"is the link

Comment: I am in the chat room. Join me there.

Comment: mr.claude i'm still unable to get the right answer this how i did the whole thing:-$$f=\rho=tan(\phi+\rho)$$ $$f=\rho-\tan(\rho+\phi)=0$$ $$\frac{df}{d\rho}=1- sec ^2(\rho +\phi )$$ $$\frac{df}{d\phi}= sec ^2(\rho +\phi )$$ $$\frac{d\rho}{d\phi}=\frac{\sec ^2(\rho +\phi )}{1-\sec ^2(\rho +\phi )}$$ $$\frac{d\rho}{d\phi}=-1-cot^2(\rho+\phi)$$ $$\frac{d^2\rho}{d\phi^2}=2cot(\phi+\rho)cosec^2(\phi+\rho)$$ $$\frac{d^3\rho}{d\phi^3}=-2cosec^4(\rho+\phi)-4cot^2(\rho+\phi) cosec^2(\rho+\phi)$$ $$\frac{d^3\rho}{d\phi^3}=-2cosec^2(\rho+\phi)[\frac{\rho.cosec^2(\rho+\phi)+1}{\rho}]$$

Comment: @ claude leibovici Mr.claude please help me out here...im sorry for the trouble im causing please help

Comment: You have the first derivative which does not involve $\phi$ anymore. Then compute the second as a function of $\rho$ and $\frac{d\rho}{d\phi}$ and so on. Forget everything now about the definition of $\rho$; just chain the derivatives. Is that clear ?

Comment: Im terribly sorry.im not understandsing anything... Please can show the mathematical way of do it... Sorry

Comment: I shall add to my answer.